# .Bat xcopy - special characters

Tags: batch-file, encoding

this is the code of my `.bat` file:

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\Users\Administrator\věc" "C:\věc"  /e /i /h
echo Done
pause
```

However it says:`File not found - výc`. See `ě` char changed into `ý`

Why is it so? Thanks

**Edit: I'm trying to copy directory, not a file**

Comment: I don't know how you are getting any results at all. I copied your text into notepad and hit save. There is a option for enocding. If you select ANSI, the ě becomes e. If you select Unicode or UTF-8, cmd throws garbage. eg:' C:\Users\ben>∩╗┐@echo off
'∩╗┐@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." etc, etc.

Comment: well in my machine it becomes `ý`... It may be because of some local settings? I don't know, however it doesn't really matter whether it's `ý` or `e`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a wildcard character for your locations:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Administrator\v*c" "C:\v*c"  /e /i /h
```

It may not be ideal, but it'll work under a few conditioms.

1. No other folders could match the expression 'v (any characters) c' (such as vehdgthc), that is true in the src and dest.
2. The dir on c already exists for the dest.

Comment: Your answer is great as it clearly states any short comings too. +1

Comment: Well, now it does this: `File not found - v*c`

Comment: This is odd - it should be looking for a folder. It appears that although using the wildcard, the XCOPY is reading the special character so the same issue persists

Comment: Try not using " " with wild characters. It's been a while since I don't use Windows but I guess it has the same effect of ' ' in most operating systems and programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the interpretation of the bat file. I generate commands which work in command line mode, but don't work in the bat file. It is not Ansi or unicodes fault since I can copy and paste into the command interpreter, and it works just fine. Unfortunately the rules for bat file interpretation don't seem to be clearly documented.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you're explaining definitively why this won't work, speculating why this won't work, or just making general observations.  The first case would qualify as an answer if you can clarify it and make it more definitive.  The other two cases don't meet the definition of an answer on SU.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to unicode and more about how the special character is displayed. Unicode characters will display differently in Notepad and Wordpad for example.

In your case, it appears this special character is confusing the XCopy command and making it think it is a file, and not a folder.

If it is an option, change it to an e and then try it again. I appreciate it's not ideal as you're having to create a new word but this should work. If it does, then you know the issue is with the character, if not then obviously you'll need to investigate further.

**Edit**

I can't test this, but you could try Robocopy (not sure what OS you're using)

```
robocopy" C:\Users\Administrator\věc" "C:\věc"
```

**EDIT 2**

Or, the issue is, your machine is not showing you [file extensions](http://www.pcsnippets.com/tutorials/how-to-turn-on-file-extensions-in-windows-7/8), so you think your file is `věc` . It is not likely! Your file should be name dot extensions

EG

```
věc.txt or věc.pdf
```

Comment: Well, I don't want to change the name of my file but it's the problem with that character, for sure. Using wild card is elegant workaround but it's still just workaround, I'd prefer clean solution though. Thanks for your responses anyway!

Comment: @simPod, can you try using Robocopy (if applicable) and see if the issue persists?

Comment: Using Robocopy: `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #1 : "C:\Users\Administrator\v*c"`

Comment: @simPod - see my Edit 2

Comment: Saw, see my Edit ;)

Comment: @simPod, please try the robocopy again without the wildcard

Comment: Still has problems with special characters...

Answer (score 0):

In your editor, make sure you use Ansi encoding, not OEM.

Comment: I'm using ANSI, it's notepad

Comment: What default ANSI encoding do you have set in Windows?

Comment: Where can i find out?

Comment: Depends on your version of Windows. For instance on XP, it's *Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Advanced tab > Language for non-Unicode programs*